# Android Room - ColumnInfo Cannot find getter for field. private final ... = null;

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

error: Cannot find getter for field.
private final com.kbb.webviewolacakmi.model.content icerik = null;

I didn't manage to add the subparts of the json to the room.
Thanks to everyone who helped.
I would be very happy if you could write a clear code example.

Json File :

```
{
"date": "xxx",
"title": {
   "rendered": "Title"
},
"content": {
   "rendered": "content",
   "protected": false
},
}
```

Data Class :

```
@Entity
data class Icerik(
    @ColumnInfo(name="title")
    @SerializedName("title")
    val baslik:title?,
    @ColumnInfo(name="content")
    @SerializedName("content")
    public val icerik:content?,
    @ColumnInfo(name="date")
    @SerializedName("date")
    val tarih:String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name="jetpack_featured_media_url")
    @SerializedName("jetpack_featured_media_url")
    val gorsel:String?,) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var uuid:Int=0
    fun getIcerik(){

    }

}
data class content(
    @ColumnInfo(name="rendered")
    @SerializedName("rendered")
    public val content: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name="protected")
    @SerializedName("protected")
    val bool: Boolean?,
){
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var uuid:Int=0
}
data class title(
    @ColumnInfo(name="rendered")
    @SerializedName("rendered")
    val ytitle:String?
){
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var uuid:Int=0
}
```

IcerikDatabase Class

```
@TypeConverters(value = [RoomTypeConverters::class])
@Database(entities = arrayOf(Icerik::class), version = 1)
abstract class IcerikDatabase:RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun icerikDao(): IcerikDAO

    companion object {
        @Volatile private var instance:IcerikDatabase? = null
        private val lock=Any()
        operator fun invoke(context: Context)= instance?: synchronized(lock){
            instance?: databaseOlustur(context).also {
                instance=it
            }
        }


        private fun databaseOlustur(context: Context) = Room.databaseBuilder(
            context.applicationContext, IcerikDatabase::class.java,
            "icerikdatabase"
        ).build()
    }
}
```

IcerikDao

```
interface IcerikDAO {
    @Insert
    suspend fun instertAll(vararg icerik:Icerik):List<Long>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM icerik")
    suspend fun getAllIcerik():List<Icerik>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM icerik WHERE uuid=:icerikId ")
    suspend fun getIcerik(icerikId:Int):Icerik
    @Query("DELETE FROM icerik")
    suspend fun deleteAllIcerik()
}
```

TypeConverter

```
class RoomTypeConverters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromTitleToJSONString(title: title?): String? {
        return Gson().toJson(title)
    }
    @TypeConverter
    fun toTitleFromJSONString(jsonString: String?): title? {
        return Gson().fromJson(jsonString, title::class.java)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromIcerikToJSONString(content: content?): String? {
        return Gson().toJson(content)
    }
    @TypeConverter
    fun toIcrerikFromJSONString(jsonString: String?): content? {
        return Gson().fromJson(jsonString, content::class.java)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the relevance of the JSON file? Where did it come from? If you are trying to manually write that and insert it then you will have issues. The Type converters will convert the title and content fields which are part of the icerik (see the answer to your other question that inserts 4 Iceriks). If the JSON file is obtained from elsewhere then to insert you need to build an Icerik from the JSON file (so you need to reverse the process used to create it to build the Icerik, which can then be inserted which will store the title and content parts of the inserted Icerik as JSON).

Comment: Json comes from wordpress. e.g : https://turkiyekripto.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=4&per_page=50  I don't have a problem when using the internet directly, but I have a problem when using room. How can I follow a solution?

Comment: You need to understand how/what to rebuild from the JSON file have a class for that and then build that intermediate class from the JSON and then use that intermediate class to build the Icerik to be inserted. Something along the lines of `        val m5 = Gson().fromJson(myjson,JsonIceRik::class.java)
        val i5 = Icerik(baslik = m5.title, icerik = m5.content, tarih = m5.date,gorsel = "whatever")` you need to ascertain what fields the **JsonIceRik** class has. Nothing to do with Room, it's the JSON handling (aka the JSON file cannot build an IceRik directly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your issue is in regard, not to room, but with the JSON handling.

The JSON file that you have shown **cannot directly build an Icerik object**.

Rather **you need to have an intermediate class** that can be built with the JSON and then use that intermediate class to then build the IceRik object.

So you want an intermediate class something along the lines of:-

```
data class JsonIceRik(
    val content: content,
    val title: title,
    val date: String
)
```

If the JSON is then amended to be:-

```
val myjson = "{\"date\": \"xxx\",\"title\": {\"rendered\": \"Title\"},\"content\": {\"rendered\": \"content\",\"protected\": false}}"
```

- **note the omission of the comma between the two closing braces**

Then you could use:-

```
val m5 = Gson().fromJson(myjson,JsonIceRik::class.java)
```

To build the intermediate JsonIceRik object.

And then you could use:-

```
val i5 = Icerik(baslik = m5.title, icerik = m5.content, tarih = m5.date,gorsel = "whatever")
```

To build the Icerik from the intermediate JsonIceRik.

The result in the database would be:-

[image]

- uuid in the title and content serve no purpose and will always be 0 if obtaining the data from JSON

  - the @PrimaryKey annotation only serves to introduce warnings -

    - *A Table can only have 1 Primary Key ( a composite Primary Key can include multiple columns though (but you cannot use the @PrimaryKey annotation, you have to instead use the primarykeys parameter of the @Entity annotation) )*

You might as well have :-

```
data class content(
    @ColumnInfo(name="rendered") 
    @SerializedName("rendered")
    val content: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name="protected")
    @SerializedName("protected")
    val bool: Boolean?,
)
data class title(
    @ColumnInfo(name="rendered") 
    @SerializedName("rendered") 
    val ytitle:String?
)
```

- Otherwise, as you can see, the data according to the JSON has been correctly stored.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest. I took your note into consideration and applied it. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @KerimBerkay updated accordingly

Comment: You took great care of me. Thank you for everything. In fact, if you come to Turkey, I would like to accompany you :) You did everything, but I couldn't understand because I was insufficient in mobile development.
If possible, I would like to send my project if you share your e-mail address with me.